# Spring Transactions: Interface v Class

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to use Spring Transactions, and failing.  When I set them up so that my web app will launch under Tomcat, calling

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus ().setRollbackOnly ();
```

when I need to roll back a transaction, but the previous DB changes are not rolled back, and I get the following error in my localhost.date.log file:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet model threw exception
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(TransactionAspectSupport.java:122)
    at edu.mayo.bsi.backslapper.model.dao.impl.TransactServiceDAOImpl.giveProps(TransactServiceDAOImpl.java:160)
```

I have

```
public interface TransactServiceDAO
```

and

```
public class TransactServiceDAOImpl implements TransactServiceDAO
```

in my application-context-config.xml I have

```
<bean id = "transactService" class = "edu.mayo.bsi.backslapper.model.dao.impl.TransactServiceDAOImpl"/>

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<!-- the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
<tx:advice id = "txAdvice" transaction-manager = "txManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name = "get*" read-only = "true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name = "*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of an operation defined by the TransactServiceDAO interface -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id = "transactServiceOperation" expression = "execution(* edu.mayo.bsi.backslapper.model.dao.TransactServiceDAO.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref = "txAdvice" pointcut-ref = "transactServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id = "txManager" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "backDataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id = "txAdvice" transaction-manager = "txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name = "*" rollback-for = "Throwable"/>
        <tx:method name = "*" rollback-for = "java.sql.SQLException"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Here's an example, a routine where a (count == 0) rollback does not undo the "delete old users".

What am I doing wrong?

```
public String setUsers (DataSource dataSource, User theUser, String store, AdminUser[] newUsers)
{
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate (dataSource);
    Map<String, Object>         params = new HashMap<String, Object> ();

    params.put ("lanID", theUser.getLanID ());
    params.put ("storeName", store);

    int count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update (kDeleteOldUsers, params);

    for (AdminUser curUser : newUsers)
    {
        int userID = updateUser (namedParameterJdbcTemplate, curUser.getLanID (), curUser.getFullName (), curUser.getEmail (), null);

        if (userID == kError)
            userID = addUser (namedParameterJdbcTemplate, curUser);

        params.put ("userID", Integer.valueOf (userID));
        count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update (kAddStoreUser, params);
        if (count == 0) // Wasn't inserted
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus ().setRollbackOnly ();

        params.put ("backslapsToGive", Integer.valueOf (curUser.getBackslapsToGive ()));
        params.put ("monthlyBackslaps", Integer.valueOf (curUser.getMaxBackslaps ()));
        count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update (kUpdateUserStores, params);
        if (count == 0) // Wasn't updated
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus ().setRollbackOnly ();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had never used 
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus ().setRollbackOnly ();
for this purpose. 
I think you should throw exception here. Best way is to extend RuntimeException. Spring transaction is aspecting method from the beginning to the end. If exception is raised transaction is rollbacked.

If you do not want this exception interrupt your flow you can throw it in this method and catch in calling method.

Comment: TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus ().setRollbackOnly (); throws an exception: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet model threw exception
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(TransactionAspectSupport.java:122)
 at edu.mayo.bsi.backslapper.model.dao.impl.TransactServiceDAOImpl.giveProps(TransactServiceDAOImpl.java:160)

Comment: It is obvious that you don't have tx attached to this method. So first you need to check if your aop:pointcut is correct. Second I am not sure that this is the best way to configure your tx. This means that you need to change your config every time you want to add new service. And it means that every method in that service will be transactional which is not always what you want. I suggest you to set your conf with <tx:annotation-driven/> and then annotate method with @Transactional and add readOnly = true where necessary on implementation methods.

Comment: My aop:pointcut is there, in the middle. Is there anything wrong with it? The TransactService handles all transactional DB calls, regardless of starting service, the only things in there are transactional. I tried using Transactional on a routine, and 8 other classes all of a sudden failed to compile.  Deleted it, and they compiled.  So I'd like to avoid Transactional

Comment: Tried throwing a runtime exception, it doesn't force a rollback.